# Is there any way to disable a CSS property common to multiple elements in a large CSS file?

Tags: css

I have a CSS file with over 1000 lines of code with `box-shadow`
property in many elements, and I want to temporarily disable it in all
the elements for testing purposes. Is there any method of doing this instead of commenting out every `box-shadow` property?

Comment: Quick and temporary: `* {box-shadow:none !important;}`

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your css file

```
* {box-shadow:none !important;}
```

above code box-shadow is set to **none** so no shadow since there are lots of shadow rule by adding **!important** this will make rule to first priority

### simple example

```css
span{color :red}
span{color: green !important}
```

```html
<span>i want this in green color but rule is in red color by adding !impotant to color green it gives first priority</span>
```